# Only one attachment is fired instead of many records

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code for which there are **79** records coming from the SP. I want to send the attachment irrespective of their data to their users. but only **79th** record is send to every user as an attachment. I don't know why.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cls_Email_Sql ce = new Cls_Email_Sql();
        List<string> ls_attach = new List<string>();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlConn))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                DataTable tb_RA = ds.Tables[0];
                DataTable tb_User = ds.Tables[1];

                string strcolorHead = "#C0C0C0";
                string strcolorDet = "#C0C0C0";

                var groups = tb_RA.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("RAName"));

                foreach (var group in groups)   // RA Table
                {
                    sbodyMail = "Dear " + group.Key + ", <br /><br />  " +

                    "As per the details available in the system, below are the summary  "+
                    "of number of documents lying with your reportees for more than five days. "+
                    "This is for your information and necessary action ";

                    sbodyMail += "<table style='width: 400px;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' " +
                                "border='0'><tr><td style='width: 100%;'></b><td></tr></table> " +

                                "<table style='width: 470px;font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height: 53px' border='1'><tr> " +
                                "<td style='width: 30px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>SR No</strong></td> " +
                                    "<td style='width: 300px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>UserName</strong></td> " +
                                "<td style='width: 120px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Document type</strong></td> " +
                                    "<td style='width: 20px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong><div>No. of docs working </div><div> for more than five days</div></strong></td> ";

                    foreach (var row in group)
                    {
                        sbodyMail += "<tr>" +
                            "<td style='width: 30px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["SR_No"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["Document_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["CountofDocNo"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                            "</tr>";
                    }
                    sbodyMail += "</table><br>" + //close of header

                     "<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";
                    string startupPath = "";
                    List<string> ls_attach1 = new List<string>();

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    ls_attach1.Add(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls");

                    string strExp = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        strExp = "RAName = '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RAName"].ToString() + "'";
                        DataRow[] dr = ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp);
                        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges(); 
                        DataTable dtNew = ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp).CopyToDataTable();
                        DataSet dsNew = new System.Data.DataSet();
                        dsNew.Tables.Add(dtNew);
                        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", dsNew);
                    }
                    foreach (var attach in ls_attach1)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));
                    }
                    foreach (Attachment attachments in mail.Attachments)
                    {
                        attachments.Dispose();
                    }
                    ce.SendEmail("test@test.com", "", "", "Information on documents for processing", sbodyMail,"AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

at

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

I get 79 records. but the attachment is going only for the 79th record only.

Comment: Can you try to send the email before disposing the attachements?

Comment: @Kld: I added that line after sending mail, still everytime it goes for the 79th record only. **why** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normally produce a simpler example of your issue without the business logic if you want people to read through it. That said, your issue is this line:

```
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", dsNew);
```

Looking at the source for the library you're using, it saves the dataset you provide to a workbook using Microsoft's Workbook.Save(). If you call it for each DataSet you want (which I think you are, from the code) you will save them all to the same path, overwriting each one.

This means, after you loop through your 79 reports, you overwrite each one and are left with the last one in the file. You should either find a way to load them all onto seperate worksheets in your book, or save them to different files.

Comment: can u suggest how to do that ? **I want to send all the RA mails with their respective data as an attachment** See this http://i.stack.imgur.com/CkPFp.png

Comment: If you include all your datatables in a single dataset, instead of splitting them up as you are doing now, saving that single dataset will include all your tables as separate worksheets.

Move dsNew outside your foreach, add your tables to it, and then do CreateWorkbook() after the loop is done.

Comment: can u suggest how are u telling by code, as I tried but still getting the 79th records as an attachment data

Comment: You could use something like [this](http://hastebin.com/kupamagutu.avrasm)

The main thing is to move the file-saving logic outside of the loop, which is what's causing your overwriting.

Comment: i tried like this http://hastebin.com/zilumoruze.avrasm for the first two row the data was properly sent. but for the third record the same attachment was sended.

Comment: Have you tried moving the attachment disposing to be after the mail sending?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118545/discussion-between-stack-and-isaac-van-bakel).

Comment: I tried like this also, but still it goes the same attachment for the third record. see this what i tried http://hastebin.com/ejehaqewew.avrasm

Comment: hi Isaac, Please come on chat. A bit of change is needed to be done